# spark rank - scala based one second and third elemnts of tuple of RDD

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd, rank

Hi I would like to assign a rank for each row based on second element and third element of tuple ,Here we have sample data . would like to add "**1**" if the third element of tuple has max value against id . If tuple's third element has same values  values , then based one second element of tuple i.e-maximum of second element tuple should have "**1**" as a fourth element  . all the other fourth elements of tuple values would be zero . I hope you understand the requirement :

```
    (ID,Second,Third)->tuple
    (32609,878,199)
    (32609,832,199)
    (45470,231,199)
    (42482,1001,299)
    (42482,16,291)
```

code:
    ***val Rank=matching.map{{case (x1,x2,x3)=> (x1,x2,x3,((x3.toInt*100000)+x2.toInt).toInt)}.sortBy(-_.*4).groupBy(*._1)***

Result: rank.take(10).foreach(println)

```
(32609,CompactBuffer((32609,878,199,19900878), (32609,832,199,19900832)))
(45470,CompactBuffer((45470,231,199,19900231)))
(42482,CompactBuffer((42482,1001,299,29901001), (42482,16,291,29100016)))
```

Desired output would be :

```
(32609,878,199,1)
(32609,832,199,0)
(45470,231,199,1)
(42482,1001,299,1)
(42482,16,291,0)
```

Comment: "I hope you understand the requirement " No, I, at least, do not. When you say "second tuple", do you mean "second element of the tuple" -i.e. `_2`? And you've not defined `id`.

Comment: @ The Archetypal Paul , Sorry.. Is it fine now ?

Comment: It's still unclear to me. what do you mean by  "has max value against id "? Has the maximum value of all third-elements amoung tuples with the same id?

Comment: And I can;t even parse this: "If tuple's third element has same values values , then based one second element of tuple i.e-maximum of second element tuple should have "1" as a fourth element ." Your code has a 100000 that's not mentioned in the requirement anywhere. And so on...

Comment: If you Look at data  i have given . First am doing GroupBy ID-> then sorting  Based on(3rd*100000+2nd) . It will give the desired result. Now i would like to replace all the max values[Fourth Element] with 1 and the remaining values with zero(0)

Comment: What's the likely largest number of rows with the same key/id value? (i,.e. is `groupBy` going to produce rows that wont fit in a partition?)

Comment: Not got time to write it just now, but use reduceByKey to find the maximum value of (element3, element2). Then join that with your original rdd. Then map over than comparing the max with the current element 2/3, setting element 4 to 1 if they match. Which brings a question - what happens if there are two rows with the same id, and hte same maximum element 2 and element 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can try something like the following:

```
 val rank = matching.flatMap { case (x: String, y: String, z: String) => 
    val yInt = Try(y.toInt)
    val zInt = Try(z.toInt)
    if (yInt.isSuccess && zInt.isSuccess) Option((x, (yInt.get, zInt.get)))
    else None
 }.groupByKey().flatMap { case (key: String, tuples: Iterable[(Int, Int)]) =>
     val sorted = tuples.toList.sortBy(x => (-x._2, -x._1))
     val topRank = (key, sorted.head._1, sorted.head._2, 1)
     val restRank = for (tup <- sorted.tail) yield (key, tup._1, tup._2, 0)
     List(topRank) ++ restRank
 }
```

The initial flatMap performs some typechecking and reorders the tuples into pairs. The second flatMap (after a groupByKey) sorts the list 3rd and 2nd elements respectively and then recreates the tuples with the rank. Also note that you will need to import `scala.util.Try` to use this.

EDIT: Modified ranking order per the comment below.

Comment: Impressive code @Rohan Aletty , Thanks So much for quick Response :)      It's perfect  with minor sorting order -  **val sorted = tuples.toList.sortBy(x => (-x._2, -x._1)) **  Thanks Alot .

Comment: That's a good point! My apologies on the wrong ranking order.

Comment: No problem you are well done :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```scala
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[4]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val testData = List((32609,878,199),
      (32609,832,199),
      (45470,231,199),
      (42482,1001,299),
      (42482,16,291))

    val input = sc.parallelize(testData)

    val rank = input.groupBy(_._1).flatMapValues{
      x =>
        val sorted = x.toList.sortWith((x, y) => x._2 > y._2 || (x._2 == y._2 && x._3 > y._3))
        val first = sorted.head
        (first._1, first._2, first._3, 1) :: sorted.tail.map(t => (t._1, t._2, t._3, 0))
    }.map(_._2)

    // assign the partition ID to each item to see that each group is sorted
    val resultWithPartitionID = rank.mapPartitionsWithIndex((id, it) => it.map(x => (id, x)))

    // print the contents of the RDD, elements of different partitions might be interleaved
    resultWithPartitionID foreach println

    val collectedResult = resultWithPartitionID.collect.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)

    // print collected results
    println(collectedResult.mkString("\n"))
  }
}
```

Output

```
(32609,878,199,1)
(32609,832,199,0)
(45470,231,199,1)
(42482,1001,299,1)
(42482,16,291,0)
```